# Install data packages for a python package

Tags: python, package

I have downloaded a python package called [CAMeL tools](https://github.com/CAMeL-Lab/camel_tools) for Arabic NLP and now I have to install its data packages. It says to run the command

```
    camel_data full
```

but I'm not sure how to do it. Should I just use

```
    py camel_data full
```

? When I do this, it gives me

> C:\Users\delar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\delar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\camel_data': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

and when I do not use py and just write camel_data full in the command prompt, it says

> 'camel_data' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

try `camel_data light` or `camel_data full` without invoking python or `py`

I have never used this in my life and I simply did:

```
pip install camel-tools
```

Then once it was done installing I did:

```
camel_data full
```

And that worked.

You can also check the documentation on how to install the data from here: https://camel-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Where should I do it? In the command prompt? When I do, I get the following error: C:\Users\delar>camel_data full    -->   
'camel_data' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I installed `pip install camel-tools` from visual studio code's terminal. Then I tried `camel_data full` and it worked. I also just tried it on my command prompt from `C:\users\rocko` so if it worked from my command prompt from the user's folder then it maybe that python may not be in the environment path. I would suggest try running `camel_tools --help` from your site packages folder which most likely located in: `C:\Users\delar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\camel_tools` If that works then I would double check your environment path for python.